# Polly CircuitBreaker - Dynamic Duration of Break

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, policy-registry

What's the correct way to modify the Duration Break on Polly?
I know in the documentation they mention implementing (PolicyRegistry).
Is there any example of this?
I was implementing Polly CircuitBreaker in one WinService.

Comment: Add your policy to the policy registry, inject the policy registry, replace the policy in the policy registry (as policies are immutable) and the next time the policy is needed, the new one is used

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the dynamic part? Do want to use the 429's `Retry-After` header to set the `durationOfBreak`? Or how do you want to set it?

Comment: I need change the durationofbreak in real time... ex: first break 1 min, second 1×2 min... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circuit Breaker was not designed to use different sleep duration whenever it breaks.

[In case of Retry you have the ability to provide a function](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Retry/RetrySyntax.cs#L182), called `sleepDurationProvider` which is called by the policy to determine the actual sleep duration before issuing the next attempt.

So, in short [by design it is not supported](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerSyntax.cs). I will show you a workaround, but I do **not** recommend to use it. I will provide a reasoning after the sample code.

---

For the sake of simplicity let's have the following method:

```
static int Probe()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Probe has been called");
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

- It prints out the fact that the method has been called then fails immediately.
- IMHO: Not a really useful function :D

Let's define a helper method which increases the time period (>> sleep duration) each and every time whenever it is called:

```
static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetSleepDuration()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
    }
}
```

- This replaces (more or less) the Retry's `sleepDurationProvider`.

Now it's time to define our Circuit Breaker policy:

```
var sleepDurationProvider = GetSleepDuration().GetEnumerator();
sleepDurationProvider.MoveNext();

var cb = Policy<int>
    .Handle<NotSupportedException>()
    .CircuitBreaker(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
    onBreak: (_, __) => {
        Console.WriteLine(sleepDurationProvider.Current.TotalSeconds);
        Thread.Sleep((int)sleepDurationProvider.Current.TotalMilliseconds);
        sleepDurationProvider.MoveNext();
    },
    onReset: () => { },
    onHalfOpen: () => Console.WriteLine("CB half opens"));
```

- We get an iterator for the `GetSleepDuration`
- We set the successive failure count to 1 so after each `Probe` call the CB will break
- We set the `durationOfBreak` to zero because we will wait inside the `onBreak` << the workaround
- We print out the sleep duration then we sleep and finally we increase the sleep duration for the next break

In order to ease our testing let's define a retry policy:

```
var retry = Policy<int>
    .Handle<NotSupportedException>()
    .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
    onRetry: (_, __) => Console.WriteLine("Retry is triggered"));
```

- It handles the `Probe`'s exception
- It retries forever and waits 0 second between each retry call

Let's wire up the policies and run the test:

```
Policy.Wrap(retry, cb).Execute(() => Probe());
```

The output will be:

```
Probe has been called
1
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
2
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
3
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
4
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
5
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
6
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
7
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
8
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
9
Retry is triggered
CB half opens
Probe has been called
9
...
```

1. The `Probe` has been called and failed
2. CB transits from `Open` to `Broken`
3. `onBreak` has been called, which block the execution for 1 second
4. `PolicyWrap` escalates the problem to Retry
5. Retry waits 0 second and issues a new attempt
6. CB transits from `Broken` to `Hal-Open`
7. The `Probe` has been called and failed
8. ...

---

The biggest problem with this solution that it is blocking. Unfortunately there is no async version of `onBreak`. (Retry does have `onRetryAsync`, in which you could use `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`)

The second problem is that it relies on the [current implementation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/CircuitBreaker/CircuitBreakerEngine.cs). This solution won't work if for example the `onBreak` is executed on a different thread and the exception is thrown immediately.