# Polly - How to achieve a circuit breaker that opens the circuit on WaitAndRetry failure and puts back retry logic on each 30 minutes if it fails

Tags: c#, polly, circuit-breaker, retry-logic, policywrap

I was used to `WaitAndRetryForeverAsync` in the past which was wrong because I believe the [Retry pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry) is supposed to handle only transient faults, such as rate limiting, 429 status code, etc. At the moment that the API I was subscribing to went offline for service maintenance which took about 25 minutes, `WaitAndRetryForeverAsync` was retrying forever in a constant interval (not exponential which doesn't really matter in this case) which in fact triggered some firewall rules on the API side and my IP was blocked for a while.

I'm trying to do what Nick Chapsas says in his [Circuit Breaker video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3U_TJZU06Ag), i.e. if it fails to retry 5 times -> we make the assumption that the service is in maintenance. So enable the retries after 30 minutes and so on and so forth until it reconnects, even if it takes hours to do (depending on how long the service maintenance is).

The question is how do I achieve that circuit breaker policy after `WaitAndRetry`'s failure?

```cs
/// <summary>
///     This class provides Transient Fault Handling extension methods.
/// </summary>
internal static class Retry
{
    public static void Do(Action action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        _ = Do<object?>(() =>
        {
            action();
            return null;
        }, retryInterval, retryCount);
    }

    public static async Task DoAsync(Func<Task> action, TimeSpan retryInterval, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        _ = await DoAsync<object?>(async () =>
        {
            await action();
            return null;
        }, retryInterval, retryCount);
    }

    public static T Do<T>(Func<T> action, TimeSpan retryWait, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        var policyResult = Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetry(retryCount, retryAttempt => retryWait)
            .ExecuteAndCapture(action);

        if (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure)
        {
            throw policyResult.FinalException;
        }

        return policyResult.Result;
    }

    public static async Task<T> DoAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, TimeSpan retryWait, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        var policyResult = await Policy
            .Handle<Exception>()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount, retryAttempt => retryWait)
            .ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(action);

        if (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure)
        {
            throw policyResult.FinalException;
        }

        return policyResult.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify are you looking for a solution, where the retry policy is aware of the CB state and adjusts the sleep duration depending on the state?

Comment: @PeterCsala, hi mate and yes. For example the following would retry `RunAsync` 5 times with constant (not exponential backoff) which is 15 seconds and it will give it 5 tries before giving up `_ = Task.Run(() => Retry.DoAsync(() => RunAsync(uri), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), 5));` . What I want is to "replace" or may I say define that behavior when it actually gives up, i.e. it shouldn't give up, instead it should go back to the retries in 30 minutes. The CB is supposed to define that behavior. Or what you said, I believe we're on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simplest solution

If you want to have the following delay sequences:

- 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 30min
- 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 30min
- etc.

Then you can achieve this by introducing by the following helper method:

```
static IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetSleepDuration()
{
    while(true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            yield return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        }
        yield return TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    }
}
```

The usage is pretty simple:

```
var sleepDurationProvider = GetSleepDuration().GetEnumerator();
        
var retry = Policy
   ...
   .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => 
   { 
      sleepDurationProvider.MoveNext(); 
      return sleepDurationProvider.Current; 
   });
```

[Under this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590352/polly-circuitbreaker-dynamic-duration-of-break/69605142#69605142) I have showed a somewhat similar solution.

#### Sophisticated solution

By default the policies are unaware of each other, even if they are chained together via `PolicyWrap`. One way to exchange information between policies is the usage of [Polly's Context](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Keys-and-Context-Data).

First let's define the Circuit Breaker

```
const string SleepDurationKey = "Broken";
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
{
    return Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(6, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
           onBreak: (dr, ts, ctx) => ctx[SleepDurationKey] = ts,
           onReset: (ctx) => ctx.Remove(SleepDurationKey));
}
```

- It breaks after 6 failed attempts and it will remain broken for 30 minutes
- When the cb transitions to `Open` then the Context will contain the sleep duration
- When the cb transitions to `Closed` then the Context will not contain anymore the sleep duration

Please be aware that with this setup the delay sequence will look like this:

- 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 30min, 30min, 30min, etc.

And finally let's define the retry policy

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
        .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
        .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
        .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync((_, ctx) =>
            ctx.ContainsKey(SleepDurationKey) ? (TimeSpan)ctx[SleepDurationKey] : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
}
```

[Under this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534878/unexpected-behaviour-using-nested-retry-and-circuit-breaker-policies-of-polly-n/69551471#69551471) I have showed a somewhat similar solution.

---

**UPDATE #1**

If you want to have the same delay sequences like what we had under the *simplest solution* section but you want to use Circuit Breaker for that then you have to use some workaround.

The necessity of this workaround is that we have a `HalfOpen` state as well, not just `Closed` and `Open`. The above delay sequences would be used out-of-the-box if we would have only `Closed` and `Open` states. But after the break duration the Circuit Breaker transitions into `HalfOpen` (*to allow a probe*) rather than to `Closed`.

At first glance the [Advanced Circuit Breaker](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Advanced-Circuit-Breaker) could provide this *"auto-reset feature"* because of its `samplingDuration` extra parameter. But unfortunately the ACB also has `HalfOpen` state.

The workaround is that we force the Circuit Breaker to transition back to `Closed` by explicitly calling the `Reset` function on it.

So, the solution is the following:

```
var circuitBreaker = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .CircuitBreakerAsync(6, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
        onBreak: (dr, ts, ctx) => ctx[SleepDurationKey] = ts,
        onReset: (ctx) => {  });
```

- I have removed the context clearing logic from the `onReset` to avoid race-condition

```
var retry = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>
    .HandleResult(res => res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .Or<BrokenCircuitException>()
    .WaitAndRetryForeverAsync((_, ctx) =>
    {
        if (ctx.ContainsKey(SleepDurationKey))
        {
            var sleepDuration = (TimeSpan)ctx[SleepDurationKey];    
            var resetSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(sleepDuration.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(-1)));  
            resetSignal.Token.Register(() => { ctx.Remove(SleepDurationKey); circuitBreaker.Reset(); });

            return sleepDuration;
        }
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    });
```

- If the key is present then I retrieve the sleep duration from the context
- I create a timer which should be triggered just before the CB automatically transactions to `HalfOpen`

  - When it triggers it clears the context and calls the `Reset` on the circuit breaker

With this "trick" we could skip the `HalfOpen` state. Please note that even though the `retry` has explicit reference to the `circuitBreaker` you still have to use the `PolicyWrap` to make it work.

```
var combined = Policy.WrapAsync(retry, circuitBreaker);
var result = await combinedPolicy.ExecuteAsync(...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I’m testing it rn. Isn’t there a more generic way to trigger the cb instead of status code 429 because I’m not sure what status code they return if they even do on service maintenance. It just fails to connect I believe.

Comment: @nop I've used that an example, since you have mentioned that specific status code in your question.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9TngPT52 I think I could do something like the following but WrapAsync doesn't have such overload

Comment: @nop You can chain [only compatible policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093593/execute-multiple-policies) with WrapAsync. You have to change: `var retryPolicy = Policy` to `var retryPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>`

Comment: oh I wasn't aware of that. Thanks! https://pastebin.com/sT1a3ZZc may you have a look at the final code? Btw, I tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: @nop It seems fine for me. :)

Comment: Btw, I want to have the same delay sequences are the simplest solution, i.e. 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 30min, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 15sec, 30min, etc. I don't quite understand how to deal with `onHalfOpen` from the link you gave.

Comment: @nop I've will update my post later today to include that version as well

Comment: That would be great and thank you!

Comment: @nop I've updated, please check it.